# Did the Dutch "zee" (sea) and "meer" (lake) diverge or did the German "das Meer" (sea) and "der See" (lake) diverge from a shared linguistic heritage?

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, german, dutch

The words for:

- **sea**; and
- **lake** respectively,

in Dutch, are:

- **zee**; and
- **meer**,

whereas the German translation of the same is:

- **das Meer**; and
- **der See**<sup>1</sup>.

This striking, almost completely opposing, contrast between the current Dutch terms and the German terms has been noted to numerous times, but my question is the following: which language has therewith diverged from a common linguistic heritage?

Please write as much information as possible, to enrich your answer. For example, I understand there are many derivative words in both languages, lending on either one of the phonetics.

<sup>1</sup> Addendum by lemontree: Interestingly, accompanying the masculine noun *der See* meaning *lake*, German also has the feminine noun ***die* See**, which in turn means *sea* again.

Comment: Note that English actually parallels Dutch here - English has a noun, *mere*, that means "lake" but is nowadays mostly limited to poetic usage. If English and Dutch match but German is different, that could suggest that the Dutch/English model probably was the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *Meer*¹ has as its original meaning something like "stagnating water", see also the related word *Moor* "swamp".

Also the word *See*² originally had both meanings, and it was originally masculine. It stayed masculine in Southern Germany, where only lakes but no sea are known, but it changed to feminine in Low German where the sea is well known. In German it specialised meanings along that line: *der See* is now only the Lake, and *die See* is only the sea.

¹ Meer im deutschen Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM02799#XGM02799

² See im deutschen Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS23282#XGS23282

Answer (score 2):

Given that 
- Slavic languages also use  a root similar to "mere" for the sea RU: "mor'e", UA: "more", PL: "morze" 
- Romance language have similar roots: LAT: "mare", ES: "mar" etc

I'd imagine that das Meer originates from common PIE root for the sea and thus is can be considered a common origin

Comment: Actually it meant lake in PIE, but "see" is a Germanic word.

Comment: And there is a *lake* called *Müritz* in Northeastern Germany displaying this root.